# Not able to set Follow path constraint

Tags: camera, constraints

i am trying to pan my camera around my Falcon 9 , but the follow path constraint's Target is not listing the curve visible in the photo

[image]

Comment: Did you add a Bezier Circle, or just a circle? What I mean is, is your "curve" an actual curve, or did you add a circle mesh instead? I ask because I see a circle mesh in your scene collection, but no curve.

Comment: You can't use a mesh, it has to be a curve. They are different kinds of objects. You can, however, convert your mesh to curve. Select the circle mesh and in the menu select Object> Convert  to> Curve from Mesh.

Comment: okay i will try that , i had added a mesh , sry